# TypeScript: Forward parameters of overloaded function to class constructor which supports the same overloading syntax

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have a class with an overloaded constructor. I also have a Factory function for that class that returns an instance of the class. This factory function is also overloaded and all overloaded syntax's of the factory function are matched by an overloaded constructor syntax.

I'm now looking for a way to 'apply' the arguments with which the factory function is called onto the constructor call, without having to duplicate logic between the factory function and the constructor with regards to deducting the types of the arguments and in the factory function then switching between different constructor syntax's and calling them specifically.

Some code to clarify the above:

```
class X {
   constructor()
   constructor(noOfRows: number, noOfCols: number)
   constructor(noOfRows: number, colNames: string[])
   constructor(????) {
        //Logic here deduct based on the arguments send into the call which version of the constructor is called and properly initialize the X instance
   }


function createX(): X
function createX(noOfRows: number, noOfCols: number): X
function createX(noOfRows: number, colNames: string[]): X
function createX(????): X {
    //Here I rather not touch the arguments at all, but just forward them into the constructor call
    return new X(????)
}
```

I've tried several things, including a rest/spread approach like below, but TypeScript doesn't like that:

```
function createX(...args: any[]): X {
    return new X(...args)
}
```

Any suggestions how to (properly) do this?

TIA,

Paul

Comment: Hi Lucero, I think you're wrong. Javascript supports this since ES6, using the spread syntax, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Apply_for_new

This has also been hinted in the thread you linked to, but that answer hasn't gotten any upvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class X {
    constructor();
    constructor(noOfRows: number, noOfCols: number);
    constructor(noOfRows: number, colNames: string[]);
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
        // ...
    }
}

interface XConstructor {
    new (...args: any[]): X;
}


function createX(): X;
function createX(noOfRows: number, noOfCols: number): X;
function createX(noOfRows: number, colNames: string[]): X;
function createX(...args: any[]): X {
    return new (X as XConstructor)(...args);
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20noOfCols%3A%20number)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20colNames%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20XConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20X%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createX()%3A%20X%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createX(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20noOfCols%3A%20number)%3A%20X%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createX(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20colNames%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20X%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createX(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20(X%20as%20XConstructor)(...args)%3B%0D%0A%7D))

While not exporting the `XConstructor`.
Another option:

```
class X {
    constructor();
    constructor(noOfRows: number, noOfCols: number);
    constructor(noOfRows: number, colNames: string[]);
    constructor(a?: any, b?: any) {
        // ...
    }
}


function createX(): X;
function createX(noOfRows: number, noOfCols: number): X;
function createX(noOfRows: number, colNames: string[]): X;
function createX(a?: any, b?: any): X {
    return new X(a, b);
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20noOfCols%3A%20number)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20colNames%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(a%3F%3A%20any%2C%20b%3F%3A%20any)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createX()%3A%20X%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createX(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20noOfCols%3A%20number)%3A%20X%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createX(noOfRows%3A%20number%2C%20colNames%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20X%3B%0D%0Afunction%20createX(a%3F%3A%20any%2C%20b%3F%3A%20any)%3A%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20X(a%2C%20b)%3B%0D%0A%7D))